# Fit the Image within the Picturebox Perfectly C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, picturebox

I'm using WinForms. In my form i have a `picturebox` that displays images, and a print preview button to print images. The `picturebox` size mode is set to `zoom`. The problem that I'm having is that i want to get rid of the white spaces on the edges of the `picturebox` without stretching the image.

What I already tried to do is turn the picturebox back color to `transparent` to match the back panel. It looked good until i clicked on the print preview button... Then i got another issue. If i match the `picturebox` color to the background for this example gray. The print preview would show a gray background `picturebox` with image in the middle.

How would i remove these white spaces in the picturebox?

```
    private void Open_Image_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            dlg.Title = "Open Image";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right-click the pb's BackColor property in the Properties window and click Reset.

Comment: Use `Transparent` as `BackColor` for `PictureBox`

Comment: The problem is that I also got a print button in my form. When i print preview the image, the back ground picturebox will become gray. It looks odd with the image in the middle and gray paper background. @HansPassant

Comment: @taji01  you asked how to get ride of the white space, which Hans supplied.  You may be better suited to give a better explanation of what you are actually trying to accomplish

Comment: Sorry, and thank you. I edited my question. @Sorceri

Comment: Why do you print the `PictureBox`? just print the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of that white space:

- You can set the `BackColor` property of `PictureBox` to `Transparent`.

To get rid of print problem:

- You can print the `Image` of the `PictureBox` and the image doesn't have such space around.
- Also if you are using `DrawToBitmap` for print, you can set the `White` as `BackColor` of your picture, then call `DrawToBitmap` then set the `BackColor` back to `Transparent`.

Comment: Okay I'm going to try it

Comment: Thank you for suggesting different approaches to solving this issue.